# INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions) crashes in iOS 13 Beta. Xcode 11 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sirishortcuts

My code is pretty straight forward.
I am not sure what is the issue and I am not able to find a solution.

```
var suggestions = [INShortcut]()

for component in components
{
    if let userActivity = UserActivityGenerator.getUserActivity(component: component)
    {
        let shortCut = INShortcut.init(userActivity: userActivity)
        suggestions.append(shortCut)
    }
}

INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
```

The app crashes in `setShortcutSuggestions`.

It works fine in iOS 12 with same Xcode 11 Beta.

Comment: any error appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the function in the main queue.

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
    }
```